# Prevent the page from refreshin when click a button

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have  an navbar with React Redux and an navbar. I am trying to add an robot to my list and it appears after when i click the button add robot the page starts refreshing and my added robots are disappering. How can i stop the refreshing on my page.
I have tried with e.preventDefault but it is not working!

```
import React from 'react';

const AddRobot = ({
    name,
    nameChange,
    addToList
}) => {
    const emailInput = React.useRef();
    const nameInput = React.useRef();
    const userInput = React.useRef();


    const clearInputs = () => {
        emailInput.current.value = "";
        nameInput.current.value = "";
        userInput.current.value = "";
    };

    const fixloading = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
    };


    return ( <
        div >
        <
        h1 > Add Robot By Name < /h1>


        <
        input className = 'pa2 ba b--green bg-lightest-blue'
        placeholder = 'Add Name'
        value = {
            name
        }
        onChange = {
            nameChange
        }
        ref = {
            nameInput
        }
        />

        <
        input className = 'pa2 ba b--green bg-lightest-blue'
        placeholder = 'Add Username'
        ///value={username}
        ///onChange={username}
        ref = {
            userInput
        }
        />

        <
        input className = 'pa2 ba b--green bg-lightest-blue'
        name = "email"
        placeholder = 'Add Email'
        ///value={email}
        ///onChange={handleEmail}
        ref = {
            emailInput
        }

        />

        <
        a className = "f50 link dim ph3 pv2 mb2 dib white bg-dark-green ma2"
        href = "addRobo"
        onClick = {
            addToList
        } >
        Add Robot <
        /a>

        <
        a className = "f50 link dim ph3 pv2 mb2 dib white bg-dark-green ma1"
        href = "#0"
        onClick = {
            clearInputs
        } >
        Reset Inputs <
        /a>


        <
        /div>
    );
}


export default AddRobot;
```

Comment: don't use <a/> this will refresh your page in reactjs

Comment: don't use `<a>` unless you need to navigate/link to other content. If you need a clickable buton, use `<button>`. And if you've put it inside of a `<form>`, make sure to say `<button type="button"...>` so that the form does not auto-submit when you click something.

Comment: I a-tag removed and i stopped thanks! Can someone add that as an solution so i can marked as solved!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the element is not a link, `<a>` is the wrong html tag for what you need.

use `<button type="button" onClick={myFunc}>Button</button>` instead so it will act as expected. You can style the button element to make it look the same way as an anchor.

Answer (score 0):

Just change this

```
<a className="f50 link dim ph3 pv2 mb2 dib white bg-dark-green ma2" href="addRobo" onClick={addToList}>Add Robot </a>
```

to a `<span>` tag or you can keep it and place `#` in `href` attribute like this `href="#addRobo"`.